# PostgreSQL to MS Access

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, psql

Is it possible to create a database in PostgreSQL move it into other computer and use this database with MS Access? How to do that?

Comment: No. It's not possible without huge pain.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Exchange. In general we ask that you try to research your problem before posting, and try to solve it using existing resources. In this case, the main question is ... why? What is the problem you are trying to solve by doing this? You've decided what the solution is. Take a step back. Why do you want this?

Comment: Why do I want this? I have to make a database for someone, but they want to use it in MS Access. The problem is, that I know how to write a DB in SQL, but I don't know the interface of MS Access and I don't have time to learn it... I prefer writing text in a console than using graphical interface.
Ok, so how about creating tables, keys etc using SQL language and paste it in MS Access (without data). Is it easier to do?

Or maybe it's not a technical problem but psychological? Should I force them to use other interface than Access?

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, I would just spin up a PostgreSQL database somewhere and have them connect to it in Microsoft Access via ODBC.

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/24-Using-MS-Access-with-PostgreSQL.html

And I would keep Access and its limitations and tradeoffs in mind while designing my PostgreSQL database.

Advanced features will require you writing pass-through queries to leverage PostgreSQL features directly, but they don't play at all with Access tables, and if you're going to be doing any updates, you're going to need custom code because pass-through queries are read-only.

I would definitely familiarize myself with Access as well:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb221186%28v=office.12%29.aspx

and go through some tutorials:

http://www.gcflearnfree.org/access2013

Actually translating the PostgreSQL database to Microsoft Access would likely be a long, tedious process fraught with pain and peril as has been said, and is not recommended.